# Panda's resampling - Get Mean for a freq. Period of TIME

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, resampling

I've a `df` like this with Timestamp as INDEX (`dtype='datetime64[ns]`) and associated values for `1Y`:

```
                     values
Timestamp   
2014-01-01 00:00:00 20.155100
2014-01-01 00:15:00 7.586481
2014-01-01 00:30:00 73.115602
2014-01-01 00:45:00 5.936765
2014-01-01 01:00:00 82.130244
```

...

Now I would like to determine the mean of all values ​​between 08:00:00 and 20:00:00 for every day,week,month and quarter?

Is der a proper `pd.resample` option? If not, any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Got some solution:

First import the `df` as follows:

```
timestamp   values
0   2014-01-01 00:00:00 20.155100
1   2014-01-01 00:15:00 7.586481
2   2014-01-01 00:30:00 73.115602
3   2014-01-01 00:45:00 5.936765
4   2014-01-01 01:00:00 82.130244
```

then apply an `time.hour` column to the `df` and apply your conditional logic:

```
df["hour"] = df["timestamp"].apply(lambda time: time.hour)

Output:

timestamp   values  hour
0   2014-01-01 00:00:00 20.155100   0
1   2014-01-01 00:15:00 7.586481    0
2   2014-01-01 00:30:00 73.115602   0
3   2014-01-01 00:45:00 5.936765    0
4   2014-01-01 01:00:00 82.130244   1

df_new = df[(df["hour"]>=8) & (df["hour"] < 20)].drop("hour", axis=1) #apply conditional logic to a Pandas DataFrame
df_new.set_index("timestamp").resample("1D").mean().head() #resample

Output:

               value
timestamp   
2014-01-01  46.139711
2014-01-02  48.794015
2014-01-03  48.818879
2014-01-04  50.030388
2014-01-05  55.124282
```